# Referencing Classes in modules

Tags: typescript

I'm  trying to Reference a Class in an exported module, how come I have to decare GameObjects twice like this:

GameObjects.GameObjects.Player

instead of like this:

GameObjects.Player in the below code

```
import GameObjects = module("GameObjects")

class game {


    player: GameObjects.GameObjects.Player;
```

etc

and in another file

```
export module GameObjects {

    // Class
    export class   Player {
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code uses *external* modules and then specifying the variable to which the module is loaded is just necessary. Please take a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841557/whats-the-difference-between-internal-and-external-modules-in-typescript) question to see what's the difference.

Comment: thanks, if I remove the 
export module GameObjects {  then I don't get the autocompletion of player in:     player: GameObjects..Player;
but it still works!