# How to include and inline external util classes into main TypeScript app?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, module, compilation, typescript

I'm using the new [TypeScript for VS](http://typescriptlang.org) tooling system to generate JavaScript programs from TypeScript syntax. I need to define my app and the utils in seperate files, and I need to know how the util "classes" and functions will be included into the main app.

1. I've heard of the `/// <reference path="....ts" />` syntax that lets you access code from external files. Does this syntax act like `include` would in C++? Would it pull the used classes/functions into the main `app.ts` file or would it simply expect the target files to exist as `.js` files in the same directory?
2. Should I use [internal modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842023/1294758) to define classes that will be included (inlined) into the main app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a `/// <reference ... >` tag to an other .ts file, those referenced files (recursively) will be compiled into the same .js file if you specify a filename to the `--out` switch. Otherwise, that same set of files will be side-by-side compiled (`a.ts` -> `a.js`).

None of this behavior is dependent on using internal modules vs keeping things at top-level. If you choose to use *external* modules, though, the story is very different (see existing material on this, probably).

Comment: I'm getting the error : "Cannot compile dynamic modules when emitting into single file" .. because I'm using NodeJS dynamic modules. Can I keep the NodeJS modules dynamic and yet allow my class files to be folded into the final file?

Comment: Not in 0.8.3. You might be able to do this when 0.9 comes out (or possibly post-0.9)

Comment: Is there any other way to simply include external files inline? Like `#include` in C++?