# When do I need a triple slash reference?

Tags: module, typescript

When Anders Hejlsberg is talking about external modules around 35:00 in the following video...

[Anders Hejlsberg: Introducing TypeScript](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-TypeScript)

... why does the file `server.ts` require a triple slash reference to node.d.ts where as `hello.ts` doesn't require a similar reference to `server.ts`?

In particular in `hello.ts` he mentions that intellisense is present plus he gets to use the exported item from `server.ts`. So what more could the triple slash reference add?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need a triple slash reference in two scenarios:

- When you are referencing JavaScript type definitions e.g. definitions for node, jQuery, etc. for a great collection see : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
- When we want to compile using `--out` you can reference your files using `/// <reference`.

You need a `import/require` combo when using *external modules* i.e. `amd`/`commonjs`. If you don't know what these mean (amd/commonjs are javascript terms, not specific to typescript) you don't have to care. Just use `/// <reference` and compile with `--out`.

PS: I have a video tutorial on internal vs. external modules: [TypeScript Modules Demystified : Internal, AMD with RequireJS, CommonJS with NodeJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1)

### Update:

Please use `tsconfig.json` for new projects instead of reference comments : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/project/compilation-context

Comment: @basarat, agree with DarkNeuron, your link is simply mystifying to me as to how it applies to this question.

Comment: I guess he's talking about adding the file to the `"compilerOptions": {"types": [], }` property of `tsconfig.json`.