# TypeScript / JavaScript - import all types

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, ecmascript-6

How can I import all types from certain file?

Let's say I have `myClass.ts` and `otherClass.ts`.
I want to import all classes from `otherClass.ts`.

I've seen few syntaxes for imports.

```
import ClassA, { ClassB, ClassC } from 'otherClass';

import * as foo from 'otherClass';

import foo = require('otherClass');

import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

1. The first needs me to list everything. I'd like to import all types.
2. The second syntax needs the namespace prefix: `foo.ClassA`.
3. I understand that the last one is TypeScript 1.4, but still supported.

Is there something like the following?

```
import * from "otherClass";
...
   var x = new ClassA()
```

Also, what's the meaning of the `{ ... }` and some of the types being outside and some inside?

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) doesn't hint anything such.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

With ES6 modules, the closest thing available to what you want is a namespace import:

```
import * as foo from './otherClass';
```

The use it individual exports as

```
foo.ClassA
```

You can see the available kinds of imports in the [`import` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import).

> Also, what's the meaning of the { ... } and some of the types being outside and some inside?

That's for importing named exports. You can read about that in the documentation I referenced or in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33307487/188246).

Comment: But this doesn't work for types or interfaces, does it? I would be very much interested on an equivalent way of handling those.

Comment: @DanielM yes it does. You just need to ensure the types and interfaces are exported from the file being imported.

Comment: In the tests I did this was not working -- the compiler complains if I do `foo.SomeExportedType`.

Comment: @DanielM make sure you're using the type or interface in the place a type or interface is supposed to be used. I use namespace imports all the time with types and interfaces. If it's still not working, I would recommend asking a new question or doing a deeper investigation into why it's not working.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Deeper research will not be needed, it was simply that my tests were too simple -- I was typing "foo." in the middle of nowhere and expecting VS Code to suggest me the types; and then tried explicitly typing "foo.SomeType" and I got an error, of course. When properly placed, it works like a charm :)

Comment: Hello , is there a way import all interface without alias . For example like this ; import *  from './index'

Comment: @user3820266 nope.

Comment: @DavidSherret Is there the concept of importing the namespace like in CSharp/VB .NET where I don't have spell Foo.Method() just Method() or reference an enum imported via
```import * as Page1Models from './Page1Models/``` it's quite a nuisance to be so verbose when in the correct context.

Answer (score 3):

You can use triple slashes import:

```js
/// <reference path="./actionsCollection.ts" />
```

They must have to be the on the first line(s) of the file.

1. [When do I need a triple slash reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684802/when-do-i-need-a-triple-slash-reference)
2. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html