# Shortcut to import all, TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there some shortcut to import all exports?

Let's say I have `commons.ts`

```
export { $ }
export { _ }
export { Controller }
export { Model }
export { View }
```

And in my `app.ts` I just use something like

```
import * from './commons.ts'
```

instead of

```
import {$, _, Controller, View, Model} from './commons.ts'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293160/typescript-import-all-types

Comment: @ApoorvKansal thanks, seems like it's impossible...