# What is the difference between namespaces and modules in typescript

Tags: module, typescript, namespaces

I've used **typescript** from some months now and i have not understand the difference from namespaces and modules yet.

I know that before they were named *internal* and *external* modules, but with both i can import classes from other files. So what is the **real** difference?

Comment: [Namespaces and Modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md)

Comment: As I understand it namespaces used to be called "modules" and came in TypeScript before ECMAScript had come up with a module standard. Now that ES has a module standard TS renamed their "modules" to "namespaces" and added support for ES modules. I don't think there's any real reason to use namespaces going forward.

Comment: Reading the "Namespace and Modules" from @Nitzan Tomer confused me more. So, do you think that i must use only modules?

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do so I can't possibly answer what you should use. I think that that page explains the difference in a pretty straight forward way. If you need modules in the sense of loading them dynamically (using dependencies) and you use a module loader (require for example) then you need to go with modules. If however you want to have global variables with structure then you should go with namespaces.

Comment: it's funny that there still doesn't exist a simple to understand explanation of  the difference and a guideline which one should be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between internal and external modules in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841557/whats-the-difference-between-internal-and-external-modules-in-typescript)

Answer (score 7):

As it is stated in the [TS-handbook](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Modules.md)
there are 2 kind of modules: "internal" & "external". The code in the internal module is written in Typescript and the "external" is written in Javascript.

In order to align with new [ECMAScript 2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)'s terminology they decided to rename them as follows:

1. "Internal modules" are now "namespaces".
2. "External modules" are now simply "modules", as to align with ECMAScript

So:

- The way you write your code is  different
- When using modules the classes are not exposed in the global scope, while using namespaces:

**Example:**

Let's say you have public namespace sequence `NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC` which exposes public class `ClassD`.
You can access all of these globally this way:

```
window.NamespaceA
window.NamespaceA.NamespaceB
window.NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC
window.NamespaceA.NamespaceB.NamespaceC.ClassD
```

without saying `window.NamespaceA = NamespaceA`

and if you use modules you have to use the "magic" above

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces are TypeScript's way of structuring code when you don't want the outputed Javascript code to use a module loader.

You can find more about namespaces vs modules in the handbook [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html).